# Substring inside string

Tags: oracle

Suppose this is my table:

```
ID  STRING
1   'ABC'
2   'DAE'
3   'BYYYYYY'
4   'H'
```

I want to select all rows that have at least one of the characters in the STRING column somewhere in another row's STRING variable.

For example, `1` and `2` have an `A` in common and `1` ad `3` have a `B` in common, but `4` does not have any characters in common with any of the other rows. So my query should return only the first three lines.

I don't need to know with which line it matched.

Thanks!

Comment: If so, there is a tag called `homework`.

Comment: @Annjawn, this tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@A.B.Cade : Good solution but could be done without any `distinct` nor `join`.

```
SELECT * FROM test t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT * FROM test t2
  WHERE t1.id<>t2.id AND
  regexp_like(t1.string, '['|| replace(t2.string, '.[]', '\.\[\]')||']')
)
```

The query won't compare the string with extra rows since it'll stop the comparison as soon as 1 match is found for the current row...

[See fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a9a7/12)

Comment: Yes, same idea - better performance. BTW, we can remove the `+` since one letter from the "other" string is enough...

Answer (score 4):

@GolezTrol's answer is a good one, but here is another approach:

```
select distinct t1."ID", t1."STRING" 
from table1 t1, table1 t2
where t1."ID" <> t2."ID"
and regexp_like(t1."STRING", '['|| t2."STRING"||']')
```

First take a cartessian product of the table
Then make sure your not comparing the same string to itself
then create a regexp from one string for comparing to the other - `[<string1>]` means that the string must contain one of the letters in the `[` `]` which are all from string1

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f235/11) is a fiddle

Comment: Nice! Will fail, though, if the string contains `[` or other reg-ex characters.

Comment: @GolezTrol, you're right I didn't think about it, but can easily be fixed - just use `replace` function, i.e. `regexp_like(t1."STRING", '['|| replace(t2."STRING", '.[]', '\.\[\]')||']')` (there are more - I know - but as an example it should do)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
select distinct
  id, name
from
  (select distinct
    x.id,
    x.NAME,
    length(x.NAME) as leng,
    substr(x.name, level, 1) as namechar
  from
    YourTable x
  start with
    level = 0
  connect by
    level <= length(x.name)) y
where
  exists 
    (select 
      'x' 
    from 
      YourTable z 
    where 
      instr(z.name, y.namechar) > 0 and
      z.id <> y.id)
order by 
  id
```

What it does:

First, (inner select) use the table with a number generator that returns a number for each letter in the name. Now each record in `YourTable` is returned `Length(Name)` times, each with another number. That generated number is used to isolate that letter (substr).

Then (subselect in top level where clause) check if records exist that contain that isolated letter. Distinct is needed, because records are returned more than once if more than one letter matches. You could add `namechar` to the outer select field list to see the letter that match.

Comment: Would adding a `distinct` to the first inner select be better or worst (for performance)?

Comment: @FrancisP It might be better. A side effect is that the inner query returns much more records, because it also 'joins' other records. I tried to eliminate those using `connect by prior id = id and .... `, but Oracle won't accept it, because it thinks I'm creating an endless loop. Distinct is the easy way out, but it may still slow down dramatically with a lot of records.

Comment: But I think queries like this should be academically anyway. In production code I think you should store the data in a more efficient way, and/or create a stored proc for more efficient querying. It's fun doing it in one query, though. ;)